# Javascript: Add timeout after every request in Promise.all Map function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, get, promise, httprequest

For the following function, I have to **add a timeout after every GET request** in array `ajaxUrls`. All the XHR GET request are in array `ajaxUrls`.

```
function getAllSearchResultProfiles(searchAjaxUrl) {
  var ajaxUrls = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numResults; i += resultsPerPage) {
    ajaxUrls.push(searchAjaxUrl + "&start=" + i);
  }
  return Promise.all(ajaxUrls.map(getSearchResultsForOnePage))
    .then(function(responses) {
      return responses.map(function(response) {
        if (response.meta.total === 0) {
          return [];
        }
        return response.result.searchResults.map(function(searchResult) {
          return (searchResult);
        });
      });
    })
    .then(function(searchProfiles) {
      return [].concat.apply([], searchProfiles);
    })
    .catch(function(responses) {
      console.error('error ', responses);
    });
}

function getSearchResultsForOnePage(url) {
  return fetch(url, {
      credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    });
}
```

I want a certain timeout or delay after every GET request. I am facing difficulty in where exactly to add the timeout.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the requests in serial, with a timeout in between each one, rather than in parallel?

Comment: @CertainPerformance That is correct.

Comment: `I have to add a timeout after every GET request` - why do you need to do that? is there a rate limit on the GET request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make requests in serial, you shouldn't use `Promise.all`, which initializes everything in parallel - better to use a `reduce` that `await`s the previous iteration's resolution *and* `await`s a promise-timeout. For example:

```
async function getAllSearchResultProfiles(searchAjaxUrl) {
  const ajaxUrls = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numResults; i += resultsPerPage) {
    ajaxUrls.push(searchAjaxUrl + "&start=" + i);
  }
  const responses = await ajaxUrls.reduce(async (lastPromise, url) => {
    const accum = await lastPromise;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    const response = await getSearchResultsForOnePage(url);
    return [...accum, response];
  }, Promise.resolve([]));

  // do stuff with responses
  const searchProfiles = responses.map(response => (
    response.meta.total === 0
    ? []
    : response.result.searchResults
  ));
  return [].concat(...searchProfiles);
}
```

Note that only *asynchronous* operations should be passed from one `.then` to another; synchronous code should not be chained with `.then`, just use variables and write the code out as normal.

Comment: How would you accumulate the responses before you do responses.map?

Comment: That's what the `reduce` accomplishes - it `await`s all responses before proceeding.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `return[...accum, response]`. What does that do exacty?

Comment: `...` is spread syntax - the interpreter replaces `...arrayLike` with `arrayLike[0], arrayLike[1], arrayLike[2]` etc. It's basically a better version of `concat`. `[...accum, response]` is equivalent to `accum.concat(response)`.

Comment: When I do that, I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: accum is not iterable` and `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined`

Comment: Got it. I should have `return accum.concat([response]);` and `return [].concat.apply([], searchProfiles);`

Comment: I forgot to put the initial value for the reducer - use `Promise.resolve([])` instead of `Promise.resolve()` or the first iteration's `accum` won't know what to start with.

Comment: I have a query, how would I fit another request where I get the value for variable `numResults` in the for loop from another GET request?

Comment: `await` a Promise inside the loop. Or, if you want to `await` in parallel, use `Promise.all`.

Comment: I am confused about the loop. It is just one GET request which is going to fetch the value of `numResults`. The logic below should be carried out after fetching the value from this request. @CertainPerformance

Comment: For example, `const numResults = await getNumResults()` and then continue with the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

I find a simple `for` loop in an `async` function to be the most readable, even if not necessarily the most succinct for things like this. As long as the function is an `async` function you can also create a nice `pause()` function that makes the code very easy to understand when you come back later.

I've simplified a bit, but this should give you a good idea:

```js
function pause(time) {
  // handy pause function to await
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}
async function getAllSearchResultProfiles(searchAjaxUrl) {
  var ajaxUrls = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ajaxUrls.push(searchAjaxUrl + "&start=" + i);
  }
  let responses = []
  for (url of ajaxUrls) {
    // just loop though and await

    console.log("sending request")
    let response = await getSearchResultsForOnePage(url)

    console.log("recieved: ", response)
    responses.push(response)
    await pause(1000) // wait one second

  }
  //responses.map() and other manilpulations etc...
  return responses
}

function getSearchResultsForOnePage(url) {
  //fake fetch
  return Promise.resolve(url)
}
getAllSearchResultProfiles("Test")
  .then(console.log)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a delay in every request then add a `setTimout()` in your function which fetches data from api

```
function getSearchResultsForOnePage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   fetch(url, {
      credentials: 'include'
   })
   .then(response => reresponse.json())
   .then(data => {
     let timeout = 1000;
     setTimeout(() => resolve(data), timeout);
  });
 }
```

Comment: Won't help at all - the requests will still be sent in parallel, all at once.